# Write value (datetime) in pandas dataframe under diff condition

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to write into "Start_time" column the value of datetime that was for first non-zero occurrence of grouped_measurement and write the last time that occurred for grouped_measurement to "End_time" column. If grouped_measurement is 0, the "Start_time" and "End_time" should equal to 0.

I have tried various diff() with diffna() options, but with no success. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import datetime

current_time=datetime.datetime.now()
L=[]
for i in range(22):
    L.append(current_time+datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=(i*500)))

# Define input dataframe
df = {'value':      [1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
        'time':     L}
df = pd.DataFrame(df,columns= ['value','time'])
# print("Dataframe is:\n",df)

print("Grouping data according to servo positions, please wait...")
df['grouped_measurement'] = df['value'].diff().fillna(df['value']).eq(1).cumsum().mask(df['value'] == 0, 0)

df['Start_time'] = df['grouped_measurement'].diff().fillna(df['time'])
df['End_time'] = df['grouped_measurement'].diff().fillna(df['time'])

print("Dataframe is:\n",df)
```

I have actual result:

```
     value                       time  grouped_measurement    Start_time      End_time
0       1 2019-08-31 19:14:42.259304                     1  1.567279e+18  1.567279e+18
1       1 2019-08-31 19:14:42.759304                     1  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
2       1 2019-08-31 19:14:43.259304                     1  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
3       0 2019-08-31 19:14:43.759304                     0 -1.000000e+00 -1.000000e+00
4       0 2019-08-31 19:14:44.259304                     0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
5       0 2019-08-31 19:14:44.759304                     0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
6       1 2019-08-31 19:14:45.259304                     2  2.000000e+00  2.000000e+00
7       1 2019-08-31 19:14:45.759304                     2  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
8       1 2019-08-31 19:14:46.259304                     2  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
9       1 2019-08-31 19:14:46.759304                     2  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
10      1 2019-08-31 19:14:47.259304                     2  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
11      0 2019-08-31 19:14:47.759304                     0 -2.000000e+00 -2.000000e+00
12      0 2019-08-31 19:14:48.259304                     0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
13      0 2019-08-31 19:14:48.759304                     0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
14      0 2019-08-31 19:14:49.259304                     0  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
15      1 2019-08-31 19:14:49.759304                     3  3.000000e+00  3.000000e+00
16      1 2019-08-31 19:14:50.259304                     3  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
17      1 2019-08-31 19:14:50.759304                     3  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
18      1 2019-08-31 19:14:51.259304                     3  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
19      1 2019-08-31 19:14:51.759304                     3  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
20      1 2019-08-31 19:14:52.259304                     3  0.000000e+00  0.000000e+00
21      0 2019-08-31 19:14:52.759304                     0 -3.000000e+00 -3.000000e+00
```

while expected output is following:

```
     value                       time  grouped_measurement    Start_time               End_time
0       1 2019-08-31 19:14:42.259304                     1  2019-08-31 19:14:42.259304  2019-08-31 19:14:43.259304 
1       1 2019-08-31 19:14:42.759304                     1  2019-08-31 19:14:42.259304  2019-08-31 19:14:43.259304 
2       1 2019-08-31 19:14:43.259304                     1  2019-08-31 19:14:42.259304  2019-08-31 19:14:43.259304 
3       0 2019-08-31 19:14:43.759304                     0  0                           0
4       0 2019-08-31 19:14:44.259304                     0  0                           0
5       0 2019-08-31 19:14:44.759304                     0  0                           0
6       1 2019-08-31 19:14:45.259304                     2  2019-08-31 19:14:45.259304  2019-08-31 19:14:47.259304
7       1 2019-08-31 19:14:45.759304                     2  2019-08-31 19:14:45.259304  2019-08-31 19:14:47.259304
8       1 2019-08-31 19:14:46.259304                     2  2019-08-31 19:14:45.259304  2019-08-31 19:14:47.259304
9       1 2019-08-31 19:14:46.759304                     2  2019-08-31 19:14:45.259304  2019-08-31 19:14:47.259304
10      1 2019-08-31 19:14:47.259304                     2  2019-08-31 19:14:45.259304  2019-08-31 19:14:47.259304
11      0 2019-08-31 19:14:47.759304                     0  0                           0
12      0 2019-08-31 19:14:48.259304                     0  0                           0
13      0 2019-08-31 19:14:48.759304                     0  0                           0
14      0 2019-08-31 19:14:49.259304                     0  0                           0
15      1 2019-08-31 19:14:49.759304                     3  2019-08-31 19:14:49.759304  2019-08-31 19:14:52.259304
16      1 2019-08-31 19:14:50.259304                     3  2019-08-31 19:14:49.759304  2019-08-31 19:14:52.259304
17      1 2019-08-31 19:14:50.759304                     3  2019-08-31 19:14:49.759304  2019-08-31 19:14:52.259304
18      1 2019-08-31 19:14:51.259304                     3  2019-08-31 19:14:49.759304  2019-08-31 19:14:52.259304
19      1 2019-08-31 19:14:51.759304                     3  2019-08-31 19:14:49.759304  2019-08-31 19:14:52.259304
20      1 2019-08-31 19:14:52.259304                     3  2019-08-31 19:14:49.759304  2019-08-31 19:14:52.259304
21      0 2019-08-31 19:14:52.759304                     0  0                           0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close! Use groupby on 'grouped_measurement' column you created.

```
df['grouped_measurement'] = df['value'].diff().fillna(1).eq(1).cumsum().where(df['value'].ne(0))

result = (df.join(df.groupby('grouped_measurement')['time']
                    .agg([('Start_time','min'),('End_time','max')])
                 , on='grouped_measurement')
            .fillna(0,downcast='infer'))
```

You might need `pandas 0.25` to use `.agg([('Start_time','min'),('End_time','max')]`.

**Edit**

Assuming time column is sorted, then the following method would not rely on groupby,

```
label_start_end = df['value'].diff().fillna(1, downcast='infer')

df['Start_time'] = df['time'].where(label_start_end.eq(1)).ffill().where(df['value'].eq(1),0)

df['End_time'] = df['time'].where(label_start_end.eq(-1)).bfill().where(df['value'].eq(1),0)
```

**Edit 2 (No 0 at datetime column)**

```
label_start_end = df['value'].diff().fillna(1, downcast='infer')

mask = df['value'].eq(1)

df['Start_time'] = df['time'].where(label_start_end.eq(1)).ffill().where(mask)

df['End_time'] = df['time'].where(label_start_end.eq(-1)).bfill().where(mask)
```

Comment: Do you know maybe how to make it more efficient? My pandas dataframe are really big and contain 2-50 millions of rows. Execution of `df['groupped_measurement'] = df['value'].diff().fillna(1).eq(1).cumsum().where(df['value'].ne(0))` lasts less than 1 second. When I execute `result=` line, it lasts over 30 seconds, which is very long...

Comment: @Tomasz, it has been optimized. If you use groupby transform or apply, it would take much much much longer than that. I guess you have a lot of groups?

Comment: Try to run `df.groupby('groupped_measurement')['time'].agg([('Start_time','min'),('End_time','max')])` to see how long does it take

Comment: In my case 'Time' column is obviously sorted before doing any operations. Using the method not relying on groupby, the time of operation has been reduced from 30 seconds to 7 seconds, which is good, but 'Start_time' and 'End_time' is always 0. On the other hand `df.groupby('groupped_measurement')['time'].agg([('Start_time','min'),('End_time','max')]) ` doesn't do what I want, because it groups.

Comment: @are you sure? I'm able to replicate the results (with Non-0 Start_Time and End_time )

Comment: df.groupby('groupped_measurement')['time'].agg([('Start_time','min'),('End_time','max')]) is simply to identify which part is taking time to run. It's not intended as a solution

Comment: You are right, I mistaked 'value' with 'groupped_measurement' in my original script with long dataframe. Now I can confirm that for 2 million rows dataframe, the time of operation is reduced from 30s to 20s. Thank you, I hope that it will work also with dataframes containing 20 millions of rows or maybe do you have any other faster suggestion?

Comment: There probably are. But I should point out that it's never a good idea to mix different data types in a single column, in this case, datetime and 0. Please consider leave 0 as NaN

Comment: Also 20s for 2million rows is still way too long. If you are running on a machine with at least 4 cores 16g, it shouldn't take that much time

Comment: @Tomasz Create another edit without 0 in the date column

Comment: When I use `df['groupped_measurement'] = df['value'].diff().fillna(1).eq(1).cumsum().where(df['value'].ne(0))` the groupped_measurement starts from 2 and I have empty rows (which is good and desired), but when I use `df['groupped_measurement'] = df['value'].diff().fillna(df['value']).eq(1).cumsum().mask(df['value'] == 0, 0)` the groupped_measurement starts from 1 and I have 0 for groupped_measurement not a 0

Comment: I am running it on 4-core i7, with 16GB of RAM memory.

Comment: After editing to `df['Start_time'] = df['Time'].where(label_start_end.eq(1)).ffill().where(df['value'].eq(1),np.nan)` the time is 1.32 seconds, wow!

Comment: Now I am fully happy with time of 1 second, thank you!

Comment: @Tomasz No worries. It seems the mixing of datetime and 0 was creating the huge overhead. Please check my edit 2. It should be the fastest one. note that `np.nan` is not required to provide in where.

Comment: Second edit also gives time around 1 second for 2 millions rows dataframe and correct output. Thank you! I will remember not to mix 0 and datetime64.dtype.

Comment: Not mix any two different types :)